# Easy way put UIButtons in line?

Tags: uitableview, uibutton

Is it any easy way put UIButtons in line in an UITableViewCell, without calculating the pixel for setting the frame width? Like that below. Picture is from Apple Mail.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is realy easy. All what you (I) need to use intensively the sizeWithFont method, like here below. ;-)

```
CGSize size = [@"Conditions" sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:16] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(200, 21) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];
```